# How to check if a given string is string literal type or other string values

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript

I have defined a string literal type.

```
type MyColor =
  | 'primary'
  | 'secondary'
  | 'accent';
```

and a React component that accepts that type or other string.

I want to set class name if the `color` prop matches `MyColor`, or the `color` is hex code such as `'#dedede'` then set `background-color` as the colour.

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  color: MyColor | string;
}

const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {
  let className = '';
  let style = {};
  if (props.color IS MyColor) { // This is what I want to know.
    className = `bg-${props.color}`;
  } else {
    style = { backgroundColor: props.color };
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={style}
    >Hello!</div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent
```

Is there any simple way to achive this? or should I create a function that check all available values?

**Update**

If I create a checking function with array, an editor with TypeScript not helpful.

```
function isMyColor(color: string): boolean {
  if (['primary', 'secomdary'].includes(color as MyColor) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

I have a typo in `secondary` and omitted `accent` but my editor(VSCode) nor TypeScript compiler not warn that.

Comment: Not sure you're getting much utility out of your `MyColor` type since in reality the type of the `color` prop just widens to `string`. Maybe just lose that type and use an array `if (['primary', 'secondary', 'accent'].includes(props.color)) { ... }`

Comment: I agree, is there something that [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w146OW) doesn't do for you?

Comment: I updated my post. It doesn't tell me my mistake like that code.

Comment: You probably want to impelment a user defined type guard. `const VALUES = [value1, value2] as const;
const isType = (value: string): value is typeof Values[number] => {
  return (VALUES as readonly string[]).includes(value)
}`